# ActiveRecord Joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm just trying to use ActiveRecord to the best of it's ability and am having trouble doing joins in the way I would like.

Here is how my models are set up:

```
class Model
    has_many :likes
end

class Like
    belongs_to :model
    belongs_to :user
end

class User
    has_many :likes
end
```

I would like to get all the likes from a 'model' object and from there get all the users that made the like. So this is what my ActiveRecord query is

```
@model = Model.find(params[:id])
@users = @model.likes.joins(:user)
```

However, what that last line of code returns is a like, not a user. Is there any way to use joins appropriately and do what I want?

Thanks,
DO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `has_many :through`:

```
class Model
    has_many :likes
    has_many :users, :through => :likes
end
```

Or you can eager load the users and do the join in ruby:

```
@users = @model.likes.includes(:user).map(&:user)
```

Comment: Thank you, not exactly what I was looking for but it works. It just seems like you should be able to at least specify which to return on joins.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the gem [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where), you could use scope merging to get your data.

```
@users = User.scoped & (Like.scoped & Model.where(:id => params[:id]))
```

This returns an active_record relation object based on `User`, which you could for instance  iterate over.

This is an alternative method to the one displayed by alfonso. His would also work.